# React native android build error

Tags: android, react-native

Trying to get react native android build to compile and run on emulator based on [quick start guide](https://facebook.github.io/react-native/docs/getting-started.html#quick-start). I am new to android dev in general. Running into this error when I execute `$ react-native run-android`

```
SSYY:test $ react-native run-android
Starting JS server...
Building and installing the app on the device (cd android && ./gradlew installDebug)...
:app:preBuild UP-TO-DATE
:app:preDebugBuild UP-TO-DATE
:app:checkDebugManifest
:app:preReleaseBuild UP-TO-DATE
:app:prepareComAndroidSupportAppcompatV72300Library FAILED

FAILURE: Build failed with an exception.

* What went wrong:
Execution failed for task ':app:prepareComAndroidSupportAppcompatV72300Library'.
> Failed to create parent directory '/Users/SSYY/Projects/react-test/test/android/app/build' when creating directory '/Users/SSYY/Projects/react-test/test/android/app/build/intermediates/exploded-aar/com.android.support/appcompat-v7/23.0.0'
Try:
Run with --stacktrace option to get the stack trace. Run with --info or --debug option to get more log output.
```

Any ideas or pointers? I did follow the whole android setup.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I had a similar problem , and after spending so much time and lots of searching about this issue the only trick worked for :

1. Please Install the Required SDKs as shown in this figure [Configure Required SDKs](https://i.stack.imgur.com/RoKdm.png)
2. If You have already installed it, so you must have to update the following SDKs:

   - `Android SDK Tool` (update it to latest version)
   - `Android SDK Platform-tools` (update it to latest version)
   - `Android SDK Build-tools` (update it to latest version)
   - `Android Support Repository` under `Extra` folder (update it to latest version)
3. You Must have at least Installed the Same version `Android API` as the installed `Android SDK Build-tools` & `Android SDK Platform-tools` version as shown in the figure [Configure Required SDKs](https://i.stack.imgur.com/RoKdm.png)
4. Make sure that the ANDROID_HOME environment variable contains the correct path of the SDK like : `C:\Android\Sdk`
5. Make sure that the PATH environment variable contain the path of the SDK/platform tool & SDK/tools like : `%ANDROID_HOME%\tools;%ANDROID_HOME%\platform-tools;`

> **Note:** Local Maven repository for Support Libraries which is listed as the SDK requirement in the official docs of React-native is now named as Android Support Repository in the SDK Manager .